# based on selected option i want to display the Select fields using ionic and angular js

Tags: angularjs, select, ionic-framework

In a parent select option have Option-1,Option-2,Option-3 and also empty also be there. When ever selecting the any option i want to display the below child select fields like if select Option 2 i want display 2 selection fields below like that same, if select empty i don't want to show child selection tags.

This is the code but i don't want to show static way I need to display dynamically

```js
function Controller ($scope) {
    $scope.myDropDown = '';
}
```

```html
<div ng-app ng-controller="Controller">
    <select ng-model="myDropDown">
          <option value="q"></option>
          <option value="one">One</option>
          <option value="two">Two</option>
          <option value="three">Three</option>
    </select>
    
        
    <select ng-show="myDropDown=='one'" >
          <option value="1"></option>
          <option value="111">1</option>
          <option value="1111">1111</option>
          <option value="111">1111111</option>
    </select>
    
    <select ng-show="myDropDown=='two'" >
          <option value="2"></option>
          <option value="222">2</option>
          <option value="2222">222</option>
          <option value="222">22222</option>
    </select>
    <select ng-show="myDropDown=='two'" >
        <option value="22"></option>
          <option value="222222">22</option>
          <option value="22222222">222222</option>
          <option value="222222">2222222222</option>
    </select>
    
    <select ng-show="myDropDown=='three'" >
        <option value="3"></option>
          <option value="333">3</option>
          <option value="3333">333</option>
          <option value="333">33333</option>
    </select>
    <select ng-show="myDropDown=='three'" >
          <option value="33"></option>
          <option value="333333">33</option>
          <option value="33333333">333333</option>
          <option value="333333">3333333333</option>
    </select>
    <select ng-show="myDropDown=='three'" >
          <option value="333"></option>
          <option value="333333333">333</option>
          <option value="333333333333">333333333</option>
          <option value="333333333">333333333333333</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if I well understand your question, you want to select item from the `select` and then show 1,2 or 3 items in the ionic list, if that is what you want, here is an idea to do that:

```js
 <div class="well" ng-show="Lang1 == '1'">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control" id="sel2" ng-model="Lang2" ng-change="changeMe()">
        <option ng-option value="1">Language 1</option>
        <option ng-option value="2">Language 2</option>
        <option ng-option value="3">Language 3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-checkbox ng-if="Lang2>=1">Read</ion-checkbox>
      <ion-checkbox ng-if="Lang2>=2">Write</ion-checkbox>
      <ion-checkbox ng-if="Lang2>=3">Speak</ion-checkbox>
    </ion-list>
  </div>
```

here is an [example](http://codepen.io/Has1/pen/XNbBqE?editors=1000#0) :

**Edit**
here is what you [want](http://codepen.io/Has1/pen/XNbBqE?editors=1000#0)
PS: this is just an example to inspire you, the real solution depends on your needs

**Edit**
what about this [example](http://codepen.io/Has1/pen/XNbBqE?editors=1000#0)

Comment: hasane@ that is not my requirement. can you check my code i updated the question. i want to show drop down based on selected the option in parent.

Comment: for example if you select `Language 2` the drop down will show 2 options, is that what you wants?

Comment: yes, if i select language 2 i need to display at the bottom 2 dropdown.

Comment: Yassine.. i need show different  dropdown when selecting the main dropdown